# How to create a custom component in JavaFX 8?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In Swing it was possible to create custom components (purely in code) by extending `JComponent` (or `JPanel`), give it a layout and then add the components manually and expose some invented getters and setters to modify the set of controls.

However I am unable to find how to do it in JavaFX 8? I figure that it must be possible, but the documentation either doesn't go this advanced or comes immediatly with FXML, in which I am not interested yet.

If it helps, this is what I want in one component:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
TextField textField = new TextField();

BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

textArea.setEditable(false);
borderPane.setCenter(textArea);

textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
    if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        textArea.appendText(textField.getText() + System.lineSeparator());
        messages.offer(textField.getText());
        textField.clear();
    }
});
borderPane.setBottom(textField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this great [video on Parleys](http://www.parleys.com/play/514892290364bc17fc56c429/chapter33/about)

It shows three options:

- Just use custom CSS if the control already exists but just needs to look different
- Extend a layout container, eg Region (Java coding)
- Extend Control (Java coding) (good for making libraries)

The video explains most of the rest. Good luck!